# Android Background Service Error : Can't create handler inside thread that has not called

Tags: java, android, gps

Here is my **task** : 
i need to run 2 background services.one for synch my mobile data to server via ksoap.another service i need  to send my gps location to server.
so i wrote this code.but when i added gpsTimer part it gives below error on load the application.please help me to sort out this issue., or tell me any other way to implement this case.

Here is my **code**

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    private Timer timer;
    private Timer gpsTimer;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {return null;}

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        timer = new Timer("BackgroundServiceTimer");
        timer.schedule(syncTask, 1000L, 60 * 1000L);

        gpsTimer = new Timer("GPSServiceTimer");
        gpsTimer.schedule(syncTaskGps, 1000L, 10 * 1000L);

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;

        gpsTimer.cancel();
        gpsTimer = null;
    }

    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        stopService(new Intent(com.lk.lankabell.android.activity.BackgroundService.class.getName()));

    }

    private TimerTask syncTaskGps = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
          Log.w("GPS Tracker", "Tracker going to run"+new Date());
          LocationManager mlocManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
          mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);    
        }
    };
    private TimerTask syncTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (isOnline() == true) {
                Log.w("Method 2", "setUpdateCardAcceptTag");
                setUpdateCardAcceptTag();
                Log.w("Method 3", "getCardBulkSerialData");
                getCardBulkSerialData();
                Log.w("Method 12", "updateStockDataFromRemote");
                updateStockDataFromRemote();
                Log.w("Method 5", "SetRemarksData");
                SetRemarksData();
                Log.w("Method 6", "SetCardSaleData");
                SetCardSaleData();
                Log.w("Method 7", "synchMerchants");
                synchMerchants();
                Log.w("Method 9", "getUpdatedCities");
                getUpdatedCities();
                Log.w("Method 10", "getNotifications");
                getNotifications();
                Log.w("Method 11", "getNextSerialDetails");
                getNextSerialDetails();
                Log.w("Method 12", "getNextSerialDetails");
                //synchLocations();
                Log.w("Method 13", "synchLocations");

            }
        }
    };
```

Here is my **error** :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Handler instead of Timer / TimerTask

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private Handler mTimer = new Handler();
private Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//DO SOMETHING HERE
mTimer.postDelayed(this, interval*1000L);
}
};

private int interval = 60; // 60 seconds

public void onCreate() {
mTimer.postDelayed(mTask, interval*1000L); //start the timer for the first time
}

public void onDestroy() {
if(mTimer != null) {
mTimer.removeCallbacks(mTask); //cancel the timer
}
}
}
```

By using Handler, you have advantages that you can reset the interval anytime, for example first you want it to run every 5 seconds, than user decide to run it every 1 second, just change the interval variable and call mTimer.postDelayed again.

Comment: dear user3381480, then how to ur code apply to my question.?i need to add two TimerSynchs.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Handler to boolean at line 16

Comment: Edited, should be if(mTimer != null) {

Comment: Then just make mTimer2 and mTask2 and different interval if needed.

Comment: thanks dear user3381480.then where is place i call to my methods.?

Comment: Edited again, place it inside the run() like on your code.

Comment: thanks dear. u saved my day & also learn more things about Handler & android threads

Comment: at last 1 question.now in your way Looper functions need to call.?

Answer (score 2):

TimerTask runs on a different thread than the UI Thread and, as per documentation, a `RuntimeException` is thrown if the calling thread has no Looper. Try changing your code this way:

```
private TimerTask syncTaskGps = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();
          Log.w("GPS Tracker", "Tracker going to run"+new Date());
          LocationManager mlocManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
          mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener, Looper.getMainLooper()); 
          Looper.loop();   
        }
    };
```

Comment: dear blackbelt.its says The method getLooper() is undefined for the type Looper in your that line.is it need to apply looper for both TimerTask declarations.?

Comment: it is getMainLooper()

Comment: thanks dear blackbelt.it is need to add both TimerTask define places.?

Comment: can you rephrase the last sentence? Still I do not see the point to run the LocationManager in a different thread from the UI Thread. Why do you need a TimerTask ?

Comment: thanks dear blackbelt i got the point from ur question. :-)
i need to get gps every 10 seconds.but it now run when onLocationChanged.any way to implement my idea.?

Comment: you have the minTime parameter for this purpose. minTime minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds. Read the documentation